# How to use condition and aggregation in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I tried to use a select query in which contains both where and sum aggreation query.But its shows error while executing the query .
Below is sample table

```
|sensorid | timestamp  | reading  |
====================================
|1        | 1604192522 | 10       |
|1        | 1604192525 | 15       |
|2        | 1605783723 | 8.1      |
```

My query is

```
select date_trunc('day', v.timestamp) as day,sum(reading) from sensor  v(timestamp,sensorid) group by  (DAY) having sensorid=1;
```

while executing below error occured

**`Cannot use column sensorid outside of an Aggregation in HAVING clause. Only GROUP BY keys allowed here.]`**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you apply `group by`, you cease particular values of all other columns.
Probably you want to either filter by values -> use `where`

```
select date_trunc('day', v.timestamp) as day,sum(reading) from sensor  v(timestamp,sensorid) where sensorid=1 group by  (DAY) ;
```

or filter by aggregation -> keep `having` but use aggregation function

```
select date_trunc('day', v.timestamp) as day,sum(reading) from sensor  v(timestamp,sensorid) group by  (DAY) having min(sensorid)=1;
```

Not clear what's your intention, post expected output if I didn't guess any variant.